# Как сделать валюту оплаты отличной от валюты объявления?

Tags: платежи

Если более подробно, то как можно установить валюту для оплаты услуг (например: подъем в топ) от валюты размещения объявлений? Возмем к примеру доску объявлений: валюта размещаемых объявлений - RUB, валюта оплаты услуг на сайте для тех кто размещает объявления - USD.
Пример на фото:
[image: rub]

[image: usd]

Данный алгоритм, реализуется на своем сайте или на стороне платежной системы?

Comment: простите, а о чем вопрос?.. Начнем с того, что обращение ненациональной валюты строго регламентируется законом. Далее: Есть платежные системы, которые принимают платежи только в рублях, есть банки, которые могут принимать на рублевый счет перевод в валюте с конвертацией по текущему курсу и наоборот. Далее есть веб-сайты, которые могут хранить одно значение цены и конвертировать его в другие валюты. А есть такие, которые могут хранить разные цены в разных валютах.

Comment: А в Вашем примере эти две валюты вообще никак не связаны.Для оплаты используется только USD, а объявления хоть в йенах могут быть, потому что это всего лишь текстовая информация, добавленная третьими лицами, информирующая пользователей о стоимости, того, что они в этом объявлении написали. Вы в этом взаиморасчете не учавствуете. А платить будут только авторы объявлений, за услуги, предоставляемые параллельно с размещением объявлений, такие как поднятие в топ и т.д.

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Постарайтесь переформулировать вопрос таким образом, чтобы на него можно было дать конкретный ответ. На данный момент мне не очень понятно, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Часто данные о товарах и услугах, чья цена формируется в валюте так и хранят и на момент, оплаты уже формируют счет в рублях. Некоторые могут объявить какую-либо свою условную единицу, и сами устанавливать её "курс", но при этом во взамиорасчетах опять же будут использовать рубли

Comment: см. Федеральный закон от 10.12.2003 N 173-ФЗ (ред. от 25.12.2018) "О валютном регулировании и валютном контроле"
`Валютные операции между резидентами запрещены`, за исключением пары случаев.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. В вопросе имелось ввиду то, на сколько сложно от 1 до 10 установить подобный алгоритм, где 1 - легко, 10 - невозможно. Суть вопроса в том, что мне нужно установить отображаемую валюту в рублях (т.е. то что будет в объявлениях, как вы верно выразились - просто текст), а валюту оплаты (поднятие в топ) уже доллары, например. Насколько это сложно сделать?

Законы и акты о валюте - здесь явно лишние.

Comment: Сложность - это вопрос относительный. Она напрямую зависит от того, кто это будет реализовывать.Для меня это может быть 0, а для кого-то это может быть невыполнимой задачей. Я думаю это стоит спрашивать у того, кто это собирается реализовывать.